# Link stylesheet to Servlet

Tags: tomcat, servlets

I need to link my `stylesheet` with the name 'stylesheet.css' to my servlet.

I already tried googling for the solution, but none solved my problem.

My directory path for my index.html looks like this:
`/usr/share/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes/index.html`

and my stylesheet lies in here:
`/usr/share/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/stylesheet.css`

In my index.html I have following line to get my stylesheet:

```
   out.println("<LINK REL='StyleSheet' HREF='/usr/share/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/stylesheet.css' TYPE='text/css'>");
```

Where lies my error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution, just had to change it to `out.println("<LINK REL='StyleSheet' HREF='stylesheet.css' TYPE='text/css'>");`

while still keeping the same directory path as mentioned above

Answer (score 1):

The "URL" you provided in the `href` attribute is actually path to the `stylesheet.css` on your **server's filesystem** - but this FS is usually not accessible for the browser, which - may be except when you are developing - runs on a different machine than the servlet engine.

This means you have to provide an URL, which the browser can use to contact the server (usually over HTTP(S) protocol) and request the resource. In **this particular case** `href='/stylesheet.css'` should be enough, as you use the ROOT webapp, so the context is empty (or `/`). By default, I would use

```
out.println("<LINK REL='StyleSheet' HREF='" + request.getContextPath() + "/stylesheet.css' TYPE='text/css'>");
```

**WARNING**

Try to avoid generating HTML output in the servlet. While it is useful from the start, just to understand how things work, use MVC or similar architecture for real projects, and JSP to define the view (or some template engine like Freemarker).